# How to replace a column with Awk with a column from ANOTHER file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to replace the `$6` from file `A` with the `$147` from file `B`. Can anyone help me with the syntax?

I tried with

```
cut -d, f6 fileA | paste -d, f157 fileB
```

but it doesnt work. I tried also

```
awk '$6 fileA = $157 fileB'
```

but the syntaxis is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to show what you already tried. Also, do you want the replacement to be done line-wise, i.e. replace field 6 of line 1 of file A with field 6 of line 1 on file B anf field 6 on line 2 with field 147 on line 2 etc., or is it a constant value from file B?

Answer (score 2):

Work backwards.  Catalogue the replacements, and then insert them as you parse the 'main' file:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { replacements[NR]=$147 } NR != FNR { $6 = replacements[FNR]; print }' fileB fileA
```

To save the output to a new file, use a shell redirect as usual:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { replacements[NR]=$147 } NR != FNR { $6 = replacements[FNR]; print }' fileB fileA > newFileC
```

Comment: It worked great...but it prints the result. How can I save the edited file? I tried adding at the end of the file > fileC.txt but it didnt work...